# es6 Array Reduce handle first item being reduced

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ecmascript-6, reduce

I want to use array reduce to group items in my array by a key.

When I use the `groupByIDErr` function below I get `obj[item[key]] is not iterable` so to get it working I use the `groupByID` function which had an undefined check as shown below.

Does array reduce have a better way to handle this? What I have done here works ok for the example I have provided but I find it harder to maintain when I have to reduce a more complex array.

```js
function groupByIDErr(arr,key){
  return arr.reduce((obj, item) => {
    return {
      ...obj,
      [item[key]]: [
        ...obj[item[key]],
        item
      ]
    }
  }, {})
}

function groupByID(arr,key){
  return arr.reduce((obj, item) => {
    return {
      ...obj,
      [item[key]]: obj[item[key]] !== undefined ? [
        ...obj[item[key]],
        item
      ]:[item]
    }
  }, {})
}

const people = [
  {gender:'male', name: 'Tom'},
  {gender:'male', name: 'Richard'},
  {gender:'male', name: 'Harry'},
  {gender:'female', name: 'Sarah'},
  {gender:'female', name: 'Kate'}
]

console.log(groupByID(people,'gender'))
```

Comment: `arr.reduce((obj, item, index)` ... check if index is 0, and change your logic to suit

Comment: thanks @JaromandaX it looks like I don't even have to change the logic, I simply add the `index` to `groupByIDErr` and it works as expected.

Comment: @ak85 If you've solved your problem yourself, please post your solution in an answer and accept it so that others can benefit from how you solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `obj[item[key]] || []` in order to make it use an empty array if `obj[item[key]]` is `undefined` (since `undefined` is falsy).

```js
function groupByID(arr, key) {
  return arr.reduce((obj, item) => {
    return {
      ...obj,
      [item[key]]: [
        ...obj[item[key]] || [],
        item
      ]
    };
  }, {});
}

const people = [
  { gender: 'male', name: 'Tom' },
  { gender: 'male', name: 'Richard' },
  { gender: 'male', name: 'Harry' },
  { gender: 'female', name: 'Sarah' },
  { gender: 'female', name: 'Kate' }
];

console.log(groupByID(people, 'gender'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a recursion function to go through the depth of an array first and then return object value.

function recurCheck(your array,key){
//if array inside array
recurCheck(newArray,key)
//else
add your reduce function here and return
}